# Выполнение одного iframe только после полной загрузки первого iframe

Tags: html, html5, iframe

Код такой:

```html
<body>
  <iframe src="1.html"></iframe>
  <iframe src="2.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

Задача: заставить 2.html загружаться после полной загрузки 1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<body>
  <iframe src="1.html" 
    onload="console.log('first frame loaded', this.src);document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[1].src='2.html';"></iframe>
  <iframe src="about:blank" 
    onload="console.log('second frame loaded',this.src);"></iframe>
</body>
```